# Rodar uma aplicação sem eclipse mas utilizando o tomcat. Como faço?

Tags: java, tomcat

Eu sou acostumada a rodar o projeto na ide eclipse mas agora eu criei uma página html no notepad++ e preciso colocar essa página para rodar com o servidor web tomcat não estou conseguindo fazer.

Eu estava dando dois cliques na minha página html mas a url fica errada, ela precisa ser localhost:8080/ e não sei como fica depois daqui. Como deve ficar a url o que eu devo fazer para rodar a minha aplicação com o tomcat sem ide?
Preciso rodar esse html com o servidor porque essa página tem conteúdo dinâmico, tem linguagem java incorporada.

Eu sou muito leiga deixo isso aqui ciente.

Comment: Você tem um projeto java que quer colocar pra rodar ou apenas um arquivo html a parte?

Comment: tenho projeto java

Comment: Consegui resolver : P

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar como resolveu o problema, assim outros poderiam se beneficiar da solução.

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que você utilizava algum plugin do eclipse para executar o tomcat. Usei por vezes o plugin Mongrel, mas há algum tempo ele deixou de dar suporte às versões mais recentes do tomcat. Deixo abaixo como instalar, configurar e executar o tomcat pelo prompt de comando do **windows**.

**Pré-Requisitos:** Tenha o JDK instalado. (irei supor que o jdk está instalado no diretório *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45*)

**Passo 1:** Faça o download (da versão desejada) do tomcat no site oficial http://tomcat.apache.org/, preferencialmente o .zip do tópico "*Binary Distributions*" e extraia no diretório desejado (Irei supor que extraiu no diretório *C:\* e renomeou a pasta para *tomcat*). Sendo assim, o tomcat está instalado em *C:\tomcat*.

**Passo 2:** Crie as variáveis de ambiente necessárias para que o prompt de comando do windows reconheça o tomcat e o jdk nos seguintes passos:

> **2.1:** Abra o "Painel de Controle" > Busque e abra a opção "Sistema" > Na lateral esquerda da janela clique na opção "Configurações Avançadas do Sistema" > Na aba "Avançado" da nova janela clique na opção "Variáveis de Ambiente".
>
> **2.2:** Na janela que abriu, na área "Variáveis de Sistema" clique em "Novo".
>
> **2.3:** Na nova janela que abriu terá o campo "Nome da Variável" e "Valor da Variável". No primeiro coloque CATALINA_HOME e no segundo campo coloque o caminho da pasta onde extraiu o tomcat (neste nosso exemplo foi *C:\tomcat*). Finalize clicando em OK.
>
> **2.4:** Execute novamente os passo **2.2** e **2.3**. Executando novamente o passo **2.3**, insira desta vez no primeira campo o valor JAVA_HOME e no segundo campo coloque o caminho do seu jdk (neste exemplo está em C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45). Finalize clicando em OK.
>
> **2.5:** Busque nessa mesma janela na área "Variáveis de Ambiente" a variável **Path**, selecione-a e clique em *Editar*.
>
> **2.6:** Na nova janela que abriu e no campo "Valor da Variável" vá para o final do texto que já tem lá e adicione um ponto-e-vírgula (;) após todo o texto.
>
> **2.7:** Adicione o seguinte texto após o ponto-e-vírgula que você colocou: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin
>
> **2.8:** Finalize clicando em OK em todas as janelas abertas neste passo **2**.
>
> **2.9:** Abra um NOVO prompt de comando e execute o comando "java" (sem as aspas) e depois o comando "catalina" (sem as aspas). Se você não recebeu a mensagem "*...is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*" significa que você adicionou as variáveis de ambiente corretamente.

**Passo 3:** Adicione suas aplicações na pasta *webapps*.

**Passo 4:** No prompt de comando digite "catalina run" (sem as aspas) para iniciar o servidor tomcat. Se a configuração foi feita corretamente o servidor estará acessível em localhost:8080. E para acessar uma página que esteja na pasta webapps/teste, por exemplo teste.html, acesse localhost:8080/teste/teste.html